# RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 224, 255] at entry 0 and [3, 224, 351] at entry 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN model on my custom dataset and i am getting the error. Don't know where i am going wrong. I have put the resize in the transforms too but its still not working. I saw many other posts regrading the error but none of them seems to be working in my case. What could be the issue?

```
#------------------------train transform----------------------#
train_transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),
    ])
    
   
#------------------------test transform------------------------------#

test_transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)),
    ])

#----------------------image dataset----------------------------#
train_data=datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(root_dir, 'train'),transform=train_transform)
test_data=datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(root_dir,'test'),transform=test_transform)

#create data loader
train_loader=DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=16,shuffle=True,drop_last=True)
test_loader=DataLoader(test_data,shuffle=False,batch_size=16)
```

Comment: Please add traceback, and show where you are getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the data in your "train" folder and the ones in your "test" folder don't have the same size.
One way to solve it, is to change the `transforms.Resize(224)` to:

```
transforms.Resize(256),
transforms.CenterCrop(224),
```